# UnityPlayer gives "Your hardware does not support this application,sorry!" message

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I've downloaded a UnityPlayer.jar that i found from a sample application and added it to my application, but It gives me this message in runtime. Can someone help!! Am i missing something. Is this a right way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated. In logs i'm getting error **Unable to find main**

Comment: Always post the error message (the whole stack trace) so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

[Unity uses ARCore](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/29/ar-comes-to-android-with-the-arcore-sdk/) for augmented reality and [ARCore requires Android 7+ with access to Play Store](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices). Check the [requirements](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android) before beginning a project.

> ### Requirements
>
> You'll need:
>
> #### Hardware
>
> - An ARCore [supported phone](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices)
> - A USB cable to connect your phone to your development machine
>
> #### Software
>
> - [Unity **2017.4 or later**](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) with [Android Build Support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstallingUnity.html) selected during installation
> - [ARCore SDK for Unity **1.3.0 or later**](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/releases)
> - Android SDK **7.0 (API Level 24) or later**, installed using the SDK Manager in Android Studio

Comment: I want to support android version 4.0+ Can u please suggest something which help in achieving it?

Comment: Sorry, sadly it's not possible. Don't argue about the facts. As described above, you can't run ARCore on Android 4. Phones with Android 4 probably lack the computation power required for running AR anyway. Also, [Android 4.0-4.3 make up less than 5% of all Android globally](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/), and nobody is going to invest in that. You'll ned to get a new phone and test on that. Look, here are the official requirements: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android

Comment: You could build an app for Android 4+ but any AR inside that app could only run on Android 7+.

Comment: If you're willing to bump up your minimum version a few versions, you can checkout 8th Wall XR. It supports Android devices running version 4.4+. https://8thwall.com/